# Multiple Select in JQuery Mobile becomes empty when I change it to multiple

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I do have a html input field select that is populated dynamically with values from MySQL database using jquery mobile. It is working perfectly but now I needed to change it to multiple select of options.
Please, see how my input was before this change:

```
<div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
    <form id = "cname" onsubmit="return submitForm();">

       <label for "id">Employee's Name:</label><br/>
       <select name="id" id="id">
       <option value=""></option>
       </select><br/>


    <input type="submit" value="Clock-In" id="enviar_in" data-inline="true">

    </form>
</div>
```

Now, see how it looks like after I changed it to accept multiple select:

```
<div id="landmark-1" data-landmark-id="1">
    <form id = "cname" onsubmit="return submitForm();">

       <label for "id">Employee's Name:</label><br/>
       <select name="id" id="id" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
       <option value=""></option>
       </select><br/>


    <input type="submit" value="Clock-In" id="enviar_in" data-inline="true">

    </form>
</div>
```

It pop up the box for multi-select the options with the "x" to close the box and everything but does not show the populated data from MySQL.
Is there any thing that I am missing?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this. After the select is populated dynamically update the select using `refresh()`.

```
//refresh value         
$('#id').selectmenu('refresh');

//refresh and force rebuild
$('#id').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: Hi @Mahesh Sapkal! Thank you for the response. Now, after your help, is working but the only weird thing that is happening is that when I click in the select input, it pop up the box, with the records from MySQL, but it closes automatically, then I have to click it again, then it stays open.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the select menu after populating .

```
$('#id').selectmenu('refresh');
```

Comment: Hi @Ashish Nautiyal! Thank you for the response. Now, after your help, is working but the only weird thing that is happening is that when I click in the select input, it pop up the box, with the records from MySQL, but it closes automatically, then I have to click it again, then it stays open.

Comment: Bind that event after refresh .